# How to change the value on an ADD EAX with C++ knowing the offset

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

So I have this:

```
Offset 0x007FF77D is ADD EAX, 0x1F7
```

And I want to change that 0x1F7 for 0x1F8 with C++, something like

```
*(BYTE*)(0x007FF77F) = 0x1F8
```

But for what I know it's not just (0x007FF77F) but I need to add something like + 1, + 2, etc. I'm obviously no expert, so I don't know what it should be.

Comment: "I have this" - extend it by the actual instruction opcode, then it will be clear what to modify, the mnemonics are not enough to get identical binary to the originally disassembled code (disassembling something + assembling it back can produce slightly different binary, assembly language was not designed to keep it stable). (that "feature" is actually sometimes exploited to watermark your own code for (C) purposes or anti-tamper detection, etc)

Answer (score 1):

In x86 machine code, if there is an immediate, it's always the last byte or bytes, coming after the modrm + optional disp8/disp32.

---

The last 4 bytes of the instruction are the 32-bit immediate, in native endian, so you can just memcpy `0x1f8` there from an `int32_t`.

`0x1f8` won't fit in a single byte.

Luckily for you, the original value is too big for a single byte, too, so we know it's using a 32-bit immediate.

You haven't shown enough info to tell whether it's using the `add eax,imm32` short form with no ModR/M byte, or the `add r/m32, imm32` encoding that's 1 byte longer.  See http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html for `05 id` (EAX short-form) vs. `81 /0 id` (general form), where `id` = immediate dword.

It's most likely the EAX short form: assemblers normally pick the shortest encoding.  But without seeing the raw machine code in the question, I can't give you a guaranteed answer.  It's like `+1`, but could be `+2`.  Or + even more if there are some prefixes that your disassembly didn't show.

But the immediate is still the last 4 bytes of the instruction regardless.